# Install the roboform lite extension in Debian Wheezy Iceweezel

Tags: iceweasel

How do I install the roboform lite extension in Debian Wheezy Iceweezel browser?

All I have is an XPI file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy that .xpi file to `~/.mozilla/firefox/<<<profile-name>>>/extensions` and you are ready to go. Read permissions on the .xpi should be enough

I encourage you to use the  http://keepass.info/ solution and its awesome plugins for firefox-iceweezel http://keepass.info/plugins.html#passifox and chromium-chrome http://keepass.info/plugins.html#chromeipass

It works like a charm and you don't need to trust on 3rd parties.